# Nested JSON with Eloquent

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I'm new in Laravel and I want to create an API . I just want to know on how to build a JSON response like this

```
   JSON RESPONSE: 
[
 {           //THIS IS MODEL FOR Industry 
 id: "1",
 value: "Accounting / Finance 
 sectors: [   //THIS IS MODEL FOR Sectors 
    {
     id: "1",       //sector_id AS id 
     value: "Accounting"
    },
    {
     id: "3",
     value: "Finance"
    }
 ],
 id: "2",
 value: "Audit / Tax"
 sectors: [
    {
     id: "4",
     value: "Audit"
    },
    {
     id: "5",
     value: "Tax"
    }
  ]
 }
]
```

The database in my industries contains

```
| id |        value       |
|  1 | Accounting/Finance |
|  2 | Audit/Tax          |
```

while my database in industry_sectors contains

```
| sector_id | industry_id |  name       |
|     1     |     1       |  Accounting |
|     3     |     1       |  Finance    |
|     4     |     2       |  Audit      |
|     5     |     2       |  Tax        |
```

Below are my partial code for models.

**MODELS**

*Industries.php*

```
 namespace App\Models;

 use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
 use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

 class Industries extends Authenticatable
  {
    use Notifiable;

/**
 * The attributes that are mass assignable.
 *
 * @var array
 */
public $primaryKey = 'id';           
public $table = 'industries';         
public $timestamps = false;

protected $guarded = [];




}
```

*IndustrySectors.php*

```
 namespace App\Models;

 use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
 use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

 class IndustrySectors extends Authenticatable
 {
use Notifiable;

/**
 * The attributes that are mass assignable.
 *
 * @var array
 */
  public $primaryKey = 'sector_id';
  public $table = 'industry_sectors';
  public $timestamps = false;

   protected $guarded = [];


  }
```

I want to use the API as a GET method and this is my partial  code but it just print the whole database in json in Industry Sectors table.

```
 public function getIndustry(){
    $flight = IndustrySectors::all();

    return response()->json($flight);
  }
```

Comment: Check out https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships for how to specify this one to many relationship and then include it when selecting

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare the relationship between `industries` and `industry_sectors` first by declaring it

```
// in Industries.php
public function industrySectors() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\IndustrySectors');
}

// in IndustrySectors.php
public function industries() {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Industries');
}
```

Also be sure to read [Laravel Eloquent Relationship Documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships) carefully